# Android Headless / GUI less Brower/library for android for getting data from the web [web scraping ]

Tags: android, android-library, headless-browser

I am working on an app that programmatically fills a form on a website and returns the response to the app.

to do this I am currently using [html unit android](https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android).  it works fine but html unit doesn't work on android 6.

as a large number of my users are using android 6 and 5 I need my app to work on android 6.

**My current solution with html unit:**

```
private fun submittingForm() {
       
        val webClient = WebClient()

            // Get the first page
            val page1 = webClient.getPage<HtmlPage>("http://some_url")

            // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form,
            // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
            val form = page1.getFormByName("myform")
            val button = form.getInputByName<HtmlSubmitInput>("submitbutton")
            val textField = form.getInputByName<HtmlTextInput>("userid")

            // Change the value of the text field
            textField.type("root")

            // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
            val page2 = button.click<HtmlPage>()
        }
```

I searched for days for a GUI-less browser but none of them meet my requirements.

jsoup doesn't help as it does not work with javascript

**My requirements:**

1. a library that gets website data
2. works with javascript ( load page's javascript and render the page after javascript has run)
3. submit a form and get result

**Can anyone suggest me a library that I can use?**